# Do "did not have" and "had not" have the same meanings?

Tags: meaning, negation, do-support

Do the following sentences have the same meaning?

> He did not have even a rupee with him to buy a loaf of bread.

> He had not even a rupee with him to buy a loaf of bread.

Comment: Yes they do.  I think the second is an older way of saying the sentence but I don't have references

Comment: See [this NGram usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had+not+even+a%2Cdid+not+have+even+a%2Chadn%27t+even+a%2Cdidn%27t+even+have+a&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), showing that idiomatically, we massively favour "do-support" in such contexts: ***He didn't even have a rupee...*** Or there's the "got-support" version ***He hadn't even got a rupee...***

Comment: When _have_ is used to mean possession, rather than as an auxiliary verb for the perfect construction (e.g, _She has seen it_), it is treated like any ordinary lexical (meaningful) verb, and is therefore subject to _do_-support. So we don't say *_Has she the tickets?_, but we do say _Has she seen the tickets?_ Likewise, we don't say *_Does she have seen them?_ but we do say _Does she have them?_ (This rule may be more common in USA English than in UK; I wouldn't know.)

Comment: @JohnLawler I think the intended interpretation has "not" modifying "even a rupee," not "have"; compare: "He gave not even an inch."

Comment: Perfectly good question about the English language. Don't know why it was closed.

Comment: The Brits use "Have you" for "Do you have [x] quite a lot. So, how this would be viewed in India is a matter for Indian English mavens. That is, none of us who have answered so far.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes,** these have the same meaning.

As Huddleston & Pullum (2002) describe it, your second example is a case of "non-verbal negation," where the marker "not" is attached, not to the verb itself, but to some other constituent, here the noun phrase "even a single rupee." But the effect of the "not" is to negate the sentence as a whole. H&P note, for example, that the following sentences are equivalent (p. 807):

1. Not all of them regarded it as a success.
2. They did not all regard it as a success.

Note that sentences like (1) do not require do-support, since the "not" is attached, not to the verb itself, but to a noun phrase within the clause. It can be the object, not just the subject; H&P give this example: "They had found not a single mistake" (p. 808). (The word "single" is common after the indefinite article but it is by no means required.)

The "lexical vs. auxiliary have" issue is a red herring here, at least as far as American English is concerned; the same construction occurs with ordinary lexical verbs, as in: "They found not even a smidgen of dirt on the car."

Other grammarians will, of course, prefer other terminology, as I'm sure the commentariat will note.

Comment: I find "they had found not a mistake" to sound quite unnatural. Perhaps there is some context in which it would sound OK, but I can't think of one. (AmE)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan It is quite formal and unnecessarily convoluted, but it doesn't sound *incorrect* to me (also AmE). I would classify it as [purple prose.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purple_prose)